# Order by FIELD in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am struggling to resolve this . I have a table like this .

```
    +-------------+-------+
    | type        | COUNT |
    +-------------+-------+
    | A           |     1 |
    | C           |     5 |
    | B           |     4 |
    +-------------+-------+
```

I want to query the table and the result must be like this .

```
+-------------+-------+
| type        | COUNT |
+-------------+-------+
| A           |     1 |
| B           |     5 |
| C           |     9 |
| D           |     0 |
+-------------+-------+
```

QUERY:

```
select type , COUNT from TABLE order by FIELD(type,'A','B','C','D') ;
```

It works fine if the column `type` has value for 'A,B,C,D' . In some cases the order by `FIELD('A','B','C','D')` some columns may not have value in table . In this cases I want to put 0 for it and construct a result .

D is not there in table . So put '0' for it .

**SHOW CREATE TABLE OUTPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE `Summary` (
  `TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COUNT` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TIMESTAMP`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: can you post the schema of your table? is the table with `type` and `count` a result set or the original table itself?

Comment: @JohnWoo I posted my show create table output .

Comment: why don't try with set count column default value as 0 `COUNT` bigint(19) NOT NULL  DEFAULT '0'

Comment: @Sathish, It will not work .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

how abt this:

```
select a.col as type,coalesce (`COUNT`,0) as `count`
from 
(select 'A' as col union all
select 'B' as col union all
select 'C' as col union all
select 'D' as col )a
left join Table1 T
on a.col=T.type
order by FIELD(a.col,'A','B','C','D') ;
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa2a0/9)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation and makes a relatively poor candidate as a dupe target.