# MySQL order by field in certain order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run an SQL Query in PHP and order by 1 column but in a certain order

i have tried this:

```
$sql3="SELECT * from extension
where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' 
ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'term', 'queue', 'ivr', 'voicecentre', 'conference', 'callback', 'intercom', 'queuecentre') ";
```

but its just not ordering at all

Comment: which field do you want order by

Comment: Load SQLFiddle to duplicate error.

Comment: [Seems to work well with VARCHAR](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52d4b/1). What is the type of the field `type` in your schema?

Comment: What is the collation of the table? That can affect how column values are compared with literal strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope use full for you.

> select a.col as type,coalesce (`COUNT`,0) as `count`
>   from 
>   (select 'A' as col union all
>   select 'B' as col union all
>   select 'C' as col union all
>   select 'D' as col )a
>   left join Table1 T
>   on a.col=T.type
>   order by FIELD(a.col,'A','B','C','D') ;

[Order by FIELD in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416153/order-by-field-in-mysql)


## SQL DEMO LINK

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  ORDER BY  case 
              when type= 'term'         then 0
              when type=  'queue'       then 1
              when type=  'ivr'         then 2
              when type=  'voicecentre' then 3
              when type=  'conference'  then 4
              when type=  'callback'    then 5
              when type=  'intercom'    then 6
              when type=  'queuecentre' then 7
          else 8
        end ASC
```

EDIT:

i guess you have to change the quotes here

```
 where client_id = '".$result2['id']."'
```

[LOOK DEMO FOR MY AND YOUR QUERY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25e41/8)

**EDIT2:**

But if you are using gotchas sql then this function (ORDER BY FIELD) will not order properly .

look this [article here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) and to fix it.

Comment: More standard SQL, but any particular reason this should work better than the original?

Comment: not tested which one works better, but i gave him other option.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i guess they work same , they took 1ms for both look demo.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson men fun du bor nära mig :)

Comment: this doesn't order as specified. its just listing them as normal

Comment: you seen my demo ? it works perfect , its something wrong with your code. please post your sample data in fiddle or in your question

Comment: that article on the gotcha is great @echo_Me! in this case, you could ensure at least one matches by doing a restriction in the where to "WHERE type IN ('term', 'queue', ...)" etc so it's guaranteed to match at least one...

Answer (score 0):

select term,queue,ivr,voicecentre,conference,callback,intercom,queuecentre from extension
where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."'

please try this give the name of the field in the order you want to select

Answer (score 0):

$sql3=mysql("SELECT * FROM extension WHERE client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' ORDER BY (type, 'term', 'queue', 'ivr', 'voicecentre', 'conference', 'callback', 'intercom', 'queuecentre')");

Answer (score 0):

Try and make sure the variable **type** is set to one of the values in the provided fieldlist.

```
FIELD(type, 'term', 'queue', 'ivr', 'voicecentre', 'conference', 'callback', 'intercom', 'queuecentre')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(type, 'term,queue,ivr,voicecentre,conference,callback,intercom,queuecentre')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM extension
WHERE client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' 
ORDER BY ASC`";
```

this works for ordering the items with the column name you used in table.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Extension,Types
WHERE Extension.typeID = Types.typeID
    AND client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' 
ORDER BY Types.order;
```

### Table Types:

- [typeID] => PK
- [type]
- [order]

### Table Extension:

- [extensionID] => PK
- [typeID]
- ...