# SQL ordering in multiple statements using IN statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$valueset1="'1','2','3'";
$valueset2="'a','b','c'";
$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY cul1 IN ($valueset1), cul2 IN ($valueset2)";
```

so that if the table was something like this:

```
id cul1 cul2
1   4    a
2   1    d
3   2    b
4   5    e
```

The order at which the sql selects is row number 3, 2, 1, 4.

Is this possible? Sorry if the question was confusing.

Comment: checkout order by `field` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416153/order-by-field-in-mysql

Comment: If you want the result set in a particular order, then you need to use `order by`.