# how to select multiple ids using mysqli and php with same sorting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to us IN to call multiple ids.. but the arrangement of ids are not the same..

here's my sample code:

```
$sample = "1,3,2,4,5";
$sql_top = "SELECT * FROM team_member WHERE pgs_team_member_id IN ($sample)";
```

the output that i get:
1
2
3
4

the out that want to get:
1
3
2
4
5

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try order by, like this:

```
order by field(pgs_team_member_id, $ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can uese order by field([Order by FIELD in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416153/order-by-field-in-mysql))

```
$sample = "1,3,2,4,5";
$sql_top = "SELECT * FROM team_member WHERE pgs_team_member_id IN ($sample) order by field(pgs_team_member_id,$sample)";
```